# PyQGIS: fixing QgsRasterLayer() TypeError with unexpected list argument

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

An error like this appears to me :
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.2\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode exec(code, self.locals) File "", line 1, in File "", line 58, in TypeError: QgsRasterLayer(): arguments did not match any overloaded call: overload 1: too many arguments overload 2: argument 2 has unexpected type 'list'

I use the sytax like this :

```
I use the sytax like this :
from qgis.core import (
    Qgis,
    QgsProject,
    QgsPathResolver,
    QgsRasterLayer,
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsRaster,
    QgsColorRampShader,
    QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer,
    QgsSingleBandColorDataRenderer,
    QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer,
)

from qgis.gui import (
    QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge,
)
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QColor

# get the path to a tif file  e.g. /home/project/data/srtm.tif
path_to_TIF = "C:/Landsat 8 Bahan KP/2016/LC08_L2SP_125063_20160806_20200906_02_T1_SR_B2.TIF"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(path_to_TIF, "B2")
if not rlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance(). addMapLayer(rlayer)

path_to_TIF = "C:/Landsat 8 Bahan KP/2016/LC08_L2SP_125063_20160806_20200906_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF"
rlayer1= QgsRasterLayer(path_to_TIF, "B3")
if not rlayer1.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance(). addMapLayer(rlayer1)
    
path_to_TIF = "C:/Landsat 8 Bahan KP/2016/LC08_L2SP_125063_20160806_20200906_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF"
rlayer2= QgsRasterLayer(path_to_TIF, "B4")
if not rlayer1.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance(). addMapLayer(rlayer2)

path_to_TIF = "‪C:/Landsat 8 Bahan KP/2016/LC08_L2SP_125063_20160806_20200906_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF"
rlayer3= QgsRasterLayer(path_to_TIF, "B5")
if not rlayer1.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance(). addMapLayer(rlayer3)
    
path_to_TIF = "C:/Landsat 8 Bahan KP/2016/LC08_L2SP_125063_20160806_20200906_02_T1_SR_B6.TIF"
rlayer4= QgsRasterLayer(path_to_TIF, "B6")
if not rlayer1.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")    
QgsProject.instance(). addMapLayer(rlayer4)
    
path_to_TIF = "C:/Landsat 8 Bahan KP/2016/LC08_L2SP_125063_20160806_20200906_02_T1_SR_B7.TIF"
rlayer5= QgsRasterLayer(path_to_TIF, "B7")
if not rlayer1.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")    
QgsProject.instance(). addMapLayer(rlayer5)

high_resolution = True

composite = QgsRasterLayer(
   "composite",[
   rlayer,
   rlayer1,
   rlayer2,
   rlayer3,
   rlayer4,
   rlayer5,
  ],
"B1",
high_resolution
)
if not composite.isValid():
    print("Composite layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(composite)

color_ramp = QgsColorRampShader()
color_ramp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
color_ramp.setColorRampAlgorithm(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
    
shader = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(composite.dataProvider(), 1, color_ramp)
composite.setRenderer(shader)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(composite)  


help me to correct this syntax because I don't know what to do anymorehelp me to
```

help me to correct this syntax because I don't know what to do anymorehelp me to